# How to retrieve post statuses of available posts?

Tags: posts

In front end I can retrieve all the possible post_statues using

```
$stati = wp_count_posts('post');
$statuses = array_keys(get_object_vars($stati));
```

reference : `get_available_post_statuses();`

but is there any function or way to get the list of post statues for which posts are available ?

Comment: "In front end" - do you mean inside a template? Where else do you need this information? You should be able to use the code you cited anywhere inside WP.

Comment: @montrealist yes. that displays all the statuses,but want the list of statuses for which posts are available .

Answer (score 0):

If you want the post types that have posts, why not get all post types and get a count for each of them (not tested):

```
$post_types = get_post_types();

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $count = wp_count_posts( $post_type );
    if( $count > 0 ) {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: for now, I have done that but would like to know if there is any function or variable that stores it ?

Comment: What for? You want to store it for a comparison later? BTW this is a different question than what you had originally.

Comment: What you understand by post statuses of available posts ? I want to create a menu that will only display post statues for which posts are available so that going to that link user will see only posts of that status, think about a guest poster .

Comment: You don't need to _store_ anything to achieve this - just generate your links and output the menu.

Comment: but, for that I need to to check manually if a post with this status is available or not , which I think, should be having a better way and felt like there may be any function or array for it, you can notice similar thing just above post or page table , but here it is created by WP_List table some how .